# What's wrong with my Xorg's config?

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, gdm

I'm using gnome under Arch Linux in my laptop with a 1920*1080 monitor on the left of it, I set the monitor as my primary display in GNOME and everything works fine after I log in. However, GDM displays my log-in dialogue on my lap-top screen every time, and I noticed that my monitor was set defaultly on the right side of my laptop. I searched and found someone said mouse's position may have effect, which did not work on me. Then I add a new file tring to configure xorg:
Here is the my condition under Gnome:

```
xrandr -q

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 290mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+1920+312 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1366x768       60.2*+
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Here is my conf:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier  "Layout0"
    Screen  "Screen0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "VGA1"
    Option  "Primary"   "true"
    Option  "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
    Option  "Position" "0 0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "LVDS1"
    Option  "PreferredMode" "1366x768"
    Option  "Position" "1920 312"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Screen0"
    Monitor "VGA1"
    Monitor "LVDS1"
EndSection
```

And this snippet may help:

```
/var/log/Xorg.0.log

[    15.229] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Jul 12 22:58:56 2013
[    15.294] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    15.294] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    15.332] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[    15.332] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[    15.332] (**) |   |-->Monitor "LVDS1"
[    15.364] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    15.364] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    15.364] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
```

After all, nothing happened, my laptop is still my primary screen on the wrong side. What should I do for now?

Comment: I have similar problem on Fedora ... (Fedora 17, 18 and 19)... and havent yet solved it.